# Setting window.innerHeight

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain me why does setting `height` viewport property:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=480px, height=120px">`

doesn't work?
The `window.innerWidth` reports 480px BUT `window.innerHeight` 210, not just 120px! As so what's the point in setting `height` property?

Comment: What is the width and height of the device that your displaying this??

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to specify `px`. Just write [an integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Well because there is no height this should be used for device support not for defining a specific size you have media queries for that.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp
```

Comment: What do You mean "there is no height"? According to: [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml) there is `height` property and can be set just like the `width`

Comment: @Ahmad Bamieh But only theoretically. As i wrote changing `height` has no effect. I just checked it out!

Comment: @Mulligun81 maybe, resource please?

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment mentioned above, you're sopposed to add the width / heigth **without** the *px* - example below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
```

But be aware, that a pixel is not a pixel depending on the endusers device

For a quick read take a look at this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Also a ref about the pixel is not a pixel

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

---

**EDIT:** OK - Maybe I got your problem now. While playing around with the viewport props i noticed, that maybe the cache of your browser played a trick on you while testing a lot. -ofc not sure if you did not clear it while testing. -- **!!!Please read the NOTE at the END if you're testing on a non-mobile device!!!**

But to give you a quick example that following changes something:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=50">
```

You should check out following 3 websites I set up for you:

All with following div:

```
div{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

http://testcode.de/test/1.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

http://testcode.de/test/2.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0">
```

http://testcode.de/test/3.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=50">
```

**NOTE:** viewport, which gives hints about the size of the initial size of the viewport, is used by several **mobile devices only**.

OFC - You should use a mobile device to test this!
If you've used a normal browser - here is your answer!

Comment: The `px` isn't required - i've checked it out. With or without the `px` changing the `height` has no effect.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE of the post, maybe it should help now.

Comment: @Mulligun81 Did you test the Sites I created for you and could you figure out what the problem is / did this solve your problem?